# Adobe Indesign XML

Tags: xml, adobe-indesign

I need to create an XML that will be exported from Adobe InDesign. This InDesign file will have different pages, and each page will have speaker notes tag. The idea is that when I will be exporting the whole document to XML, I'll have a file with the different speaker notes tag for each page. I have done this and it works, the problem comes when I move the pages inside Indesign around (change the order), the order of these speaker notes does not change.  Is there any way that when I change the order of a page, the order of the XML tag also is changed?

I need to create an XML so I can read it later in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Nope straight way. XML is a text flow so when you reorder pages, text just reflows without concern for the previous page location. You can use scripts that will break story apart. Then content should be attached to pages.
http://indesignsecrets.com/splitting-up-threaded-stories-into-separate-frames.php